# Resize Sentinel 2 yields an image with 0 values

Tags: python, resize, sentinel2

I'm trying to resize an NDVI image (derived by Sentinel 2 bands) with different methods in Python, but I always get an image whose values are 0.

I want that my image's dimensions are divisible by 5.

Here is my original image.

[NDVI original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxTrV.jpg)

I tried different methods, for example using cv2:

```
new_size = np.asarray(image1.shape) /5
new_size = new_size.astype(int) *5
image1 = cv2.resize(image1.astype('float32'), (new_size[0],new_size[1]))
```

And this is the result

[Resized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnLPO.jpg)

Other methods (pillow, gdal, rasterio) return the same result. Does anyone know how to correctly resize the image?

Comment: Please ensure your code is [mcve] and you include the input images.

Answer (score 0):

We need to convert `image1` to a `numpy` `array` in order to get its `shape`, apply `astype()`, etc.:

```
new_size = np.asarray(np.array(image1).shape) /5
new_size = new_size.astype(int) *5
image1 = cv2.resize(np.array(image1).astype('float32'), (new_size[0],new_size[1]))
```

To display the `image1` `array` as RGBA:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image1 = image1 / 255.0
plt.imshow(image1)
```

or just RGB:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image1 = image1[:, :, :-1] / 255.0
plt.imshow(image1)
```